# Video Player with Multiple Angle or View using Video.Js

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I was wondering if its possible to create a Video Player with video.js that allow user to interact with the player, so I want user to be able to stream/view the video with different angle by clicking the button on the player?

Answer (score 0):

To view different angles you need either different video streams or a video stream which includes content outside the current user view, e.g. a 360 degree video.

For the case with multiple videos, you can either:

- have multiple video elements in your web app each streaming a different stream showing the scene from a different angle, and use your buttons to switch between them (or use the buttons to make one the main view and have the the other views also available but smaller)
- have a single video element and switch the source of the video element when you click on a button. This may mean a slight delay as the video from the new viewpoint is loaded.

For the 360 degree video case you need to use a HTML5 video player which supports 360 degree video - e.g.:

- Using a plugin for videoJS like https://github.com/videojs/videojs-vr